# Proportionally scaling an image and adding a border in React Native

Tags: react-native

I am trying to create an image with a border. It works fine by itself, however, I am wanting to resize the image by using the `resizeMode='contain'` option. The problem with doing this is that the border fills the entire width of the parent element that it is containing and not just around the picture. My code is as follows:

```
const styles = {
     image: {
          borderColor: 'black',
          borderStyle: 'solid',
          borderWidth: 5,
          width: '100%',
          height: '100%' 
     }
}
```

and...

```
<View style={{height: 200}}>
    <Image resizeMode='contain' style={styles.image} source={require('myimage.jpg')} />
</View>
```

I assume the border is filling the container size by using the original '100%`. What can I do to get the image to resize proportionally to a height of 200 and have a border around it?

Comment: Do you want to show landscape or portrait image?

Comment: @DevLover Both, but why does it matter? Either way the border needs to go around the width/height of the Image, not the width/height of the View.

Comment: I think you should calc the width and height of image and not use the resizeMode="contain"

Answer (score 1):

```
<View style={{height: 200 , borderWidth : 5 , borderColor: 'black',borderStyle: 'solid'}}>
   <Image resizeMode='contain' style={{width: 195 , height : 195 }} source={require('myimage.jpg')} />
</View>
```

Give the borderWidth in View style and minus the borderWidth from images height and width . Hope this help .

Comment: What do you mean? That applies the border to the View, so if the View is wider than the image, it will still not be surrounding the image.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to apply a proportionally border to an image with `resizeMode: 'contain'`. You can use `Dimensions` and `Image.resolveAssetSource` (*for bundled images*) to calculate the aspect ratio and have the exact resized image width and height:

In `componentDidMount` or in `useEffect`:

```js
const [width, setWidth] = useState(0);
const [height, setHeight] = useState(0);

useEffect(() => {
  const { width, height } = Image.resolveAssetSource(require('./assets/lambo.jpg'));
  const winSize = Dimensions.get('window');

  setWidth(winSize.width);
  setHeight((winSize.width / width) * height);
}, []);
```

and then render it:

```js
return (
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <Image source={require('./assets/lambo.jpg')} style={[styles.image, { width, height }]}/>
  </View>
);
```

with styles:

```js
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    borderWidth: 5,
    borderColor: 'red'
  },
  image: {
    borderWidth: 5,
    borderColor: 'green',
  }
});
```

will have this result:

[image: RN image proportionally border]

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to do so with remote images and without relying on your full screen width measurements. First you need to determine boundaries for your image component that resized image should not cross. It it essentially defining `width` and `height` within which image will be contained. I am passing these as `width` and `height` props to `ImageWithBorders` (green borders on screenshot)

After that you can get remote image dimensions via `Image.getSize`, calculate ratio and do some math determining proper view dimensions for views

```
class ImageWithBorders extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      // image wrapper dimensions
      iWidth: null,
      iHeight: null,
      // image dimensions
      iiWidth: null,
      iiHeight: null,
      // outer wrapper dimensions
      vWidth: null,
      vHeight: null
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    Image.getSize(this.props.source,
      (iWidth, iHeight) => {
        this.setState({ iWidth, iHeight })
      }
    )
  }

  // using onLayout in case non-numeric dimensions were passed
  _onLayout = ({ nativeEvent: { layout: { height, width } } }) => {
    this.setState({ vWidth: width, vHeight: height })
  };

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    const {
      iWidth: oldiWidth,
      iHeight: oldiHeight,
      vWidth: oldvWidth,
      vHeight: oldvHeight
    } = prevState
    const {
      iWidth,
      iHeight,
      vWidth,
      vHeight
    } = this.state
    if (oldiWidth === null || oldiHeight === null || oldvWidth === null || oldvHeight === null) {
      if (iWidth && iHeight && vWidth && vHeight) {
        // at this moment both view and remote image were measured
        // now use some math to calculate proper sizes for all views
        const { borderWidth } = this.props
        const border2 = borderWidth * 2
        if (vWidth - border2 < vHeight - border2) {
          const newImageWidth = vWidth - border2
          const imageRatio = iHeight / iWidth
          const newImageHeight = newImageWidth * imageRatio
          this.setState({
            iHeight: newImageHeight + border2,
            iWidth: vWidth,
            iiHeight: newImageHeight,
            iiWidth: newImageWidth,
            measured: true
          })
        } else {
          const newImageHeight = vHeight - border2
          const imageRatio = iHeight / iWidth
          const newImageWidth = newImageHeight / imageRatio
          this.setState({
            iHeight: vHeight,
            iWidth: newImageWidth + border2,
            iiHeight: newImageHeight,
            iiWidth: newImageWidth,
            measured: true
          })
        }
      }
    }
  }

  render() {
    const { source, height = 0, width = 0, resizeContainer = false } = this.props
    const outerWidth = resizeContainer ? this.state.measured ? this.state.iWidth : width : width
    const outerHeight = resizeContainer ? this.state.measured ? this.state.iHeight : height : height
    return (
      <View
        style={{
          width: outerWidth,
          height: outerHeight,
          borderWidth: 1,
          borderColor: 'green',
          alignItems: 'center',
          justifyContent: 'center'
        }}
        onLayout={this._onLayout}
      >
        <View
          style={{
            width: this.state.iWidth || 0,
            height: this.state.iHeight || 0,

            backgroundColor: 'red',
            alignItems: 'center',
            justifyContent: 'center'
          }}
        >
          <Image
            source={source}
            style={{
              width: this.state.iiWidth,
              height: this.state.iiHeight,
            }}
            resizeMode={'contain'}
          />
        </View>
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

use it like this

```
const App = () => {
  return (
    <View
      style={{
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        ...StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject
      }}
    >
      <ImageWithBorders
        source={{ uri: 'https://i.imgur.com/BWrNPE4.png' }}
        borderWidth={13}
        height={400}
        width={260}
        resizeContainer={false} // or true
      />
      <ImageWithBorders
        source={{ uri: 'https://i.imgur.com/BWrNPE4.png' }}
        borderWidth={5}
        height={100}
        width={260}
        resizeContainer={false} // or true
      />
    </View>
  )
}
```

`resizeContainer` prop will resize your image to the final width and height as opposed to staying original width and height if it's off

`resizeContainer` set to false:

[image: with resizeContainer set to false]

`resizeContainer` set to true:

[image: with resizeContainer set to true]

This of course is just a minimal working example. You may want to add additional features like passing width and height in styles, changing border color, and rerunning calculations in case your props change dynamically (now it will only resize once, if you change e.g. borderWidth during runtime it will not resize again)